# `useReducer` failing when used in `react-router` route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

Using `useReducer` is throwing an error which tells me that rules of hooks are broken. Why is that happening? Is there and easy way to fix it?

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useReducer, Reducer } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  RouteComponentProps,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const HelloRoute: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(state => state, {});
  return <div>Hello Route</div>;
};
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" render={HelloRoute} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-breeze-3w7bv)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in this line

```js
<Route path="/" render={HelloRoute} />
```

`render` accepts a function not a component. Do to fix this had to wrap it in arrow function:

```js
<Route path="/" render={(props) => <HelloRoute {...props}/>} />
```

Comment: another option is to use `component`, instead of `render`, as in: `<Route path="/" component={HelloRoute} />`.